# Jupyterlab no autocompletion with tab and Cython classes

Tags: python, cython, jupyter-lab

I have a problem with Tab complete with a cython class (see below).
Tab complete works only on the first level:

```
A1  = A()
A1. <= Tab shows now optimizer 
A1.optimizer. <= Tab shows nothing :(
```

What is missing in my Cython class below, that Tab complete works? Is this also the case with regular Python classes?

```
cdef class optimizer():

    cdef:
        uint32_t u32_error

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.u32_error = 0

    def __dealloc__(self):
        pass

    cdef uint32_t u32_calc_error(self, bool_t* x, bool_t* ref, uint32_t N):

        return 42

    cpdef uint32_t optimize(self):
        #self.u32_calc_error
        self.u32_error += 1
        return self.u32_error

    @property
    def error(self):
        return self.u32_error

cdef class A(B):
    """
    File: A.pxd
    'Optimizer' 
    cdef class A(B):
        ...
        ...

    """

    cdef:
        public optimizer optimizer

    def __cinit__(self, int N = 1):
        self.optimizer = optimizer()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self, int N = 1):
        super().__init__(N = N)
```

Comment: "Is this also the case with regular Python classes?": I don't know, but this is of course very easy to test yourself, by creating two classes and implementing one as a member of the other.

Comment: Works fine for normal Python classes, so may simply be a Cython issue, with the non-Python-esque `cdef class` definition.

Comment: since I'm banned from answering any questions (and I don't know why) I will place my answer here:  The solution to this problem is to move the object initialization `self.optimizer = optimizer()` from the `__cinit__` to the `__init__` method: